# What is the return type "BST&" meaning?

Tags: c++, class, types, binary-search-tree, member

I tried to implement a simple BST with a member of class that insert a value into the tree. I followed the snipping code like below:

```
class BST {
public:
    int value;
    BST* left;
    BST* right;

    BST(int val);
    BST& insert(int val);
};
```

But I don't understand what the return type **BST&** means. What does it mean ?

Comment: That is a **reference**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reference to an instance of BST. It means that you can change the BST through that reference, e.g.:

```
BST tree(1);
BST &newNode = tree.insert(3);
newNode.value = 4;
```

The code snippet above will create a tree with value 1, then insert a node with value 3, but replace that value with 4 in the third line.

For more information about C++ references, consider reading:

[What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in)

Comment: @HieuNa If this answers your question, consider marking the post as *accepted answer* by clicking the check-mark icon.